# Eigenvector of 2-by-2 unitary matrix in spherical coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I was reading basic quantum mechanics, and stumbled upon this math problem.

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & e^{-i\phi} \sin \theta \\ e^{i\phi}\sin\theta & -\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

Here I need to find the eigen values and eigen vectors corresponding to this matrix. I have successfully found out the Eigen Value of this vector, which is +1, and -1.

When I am trying to find the eigen vector, I am getting lost. I have been to this position (by choosing eigen value = +1) -->

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta-1 & e^{-i\phi} \sin \theta\\ e^{i\phi}\sin\theta & -\cos\theta-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
The answer is $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}$.

Whatever solution I try, I am not reaching to this solution. Can anyone of you please at least show me the right direction?

My background is NOT hardcore maths, and I am a software engineer, studying quantum mechanics and quantum computing by passion. Sorry if this question sounds silly. But any help is appreciated. I need to solve it to move to the forward chapters. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point here are the double-angle identities from trigonometry:
$$\cos\theta=1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}=2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-1,\quad \sin\theta=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}.$$ Inserting these into the second matrix of interest and simplifying a little gives

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta-1 & e^{-i\phi} \sin \theta\\ e^{i\phi}\sin\theta & -\cos\theta-1\end{pmatrix}
&=\begin{pmatrix} (1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2})-1 & e^{-i\phi} \cdot 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\ e^{i\phi}\cdot 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} & -(2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-1)-1\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix} -2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}  & 2e^{-i\phi} \sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\ 2e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} & -2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}\\
&=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \cos\frac{\theta}{2}
\begin{pmatrix} -\sin\frac{\theta}{2}/\cos\frac{\theta}{2}  & e^{-i\phi} \\ e^{i\phi} & -\cos\frac{\theta}{2}/\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{align}
The prefactor is generally non-zero, so $(x_1,x_2)$ must be annihilated by the remaining matrix. Typically one then deduces $x_1,x_2$ "by inspection", i.e., by looking at this matrix and reading off the answer. But to be more explicit, we need
$$\begin{pmatrix} -\sin\frac{\theta}{2}/\cos\frac{\theta}{2}  & e^{-i\phi}\\ e^{i\phi} & -\cos\frac{\theta}{2}/\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 e^{-i \phi} -x_1 \sin\frac{\theta}{2}/\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\ x_1 e^{i\phi} -x_2 \cos\frac{\theta}{2}/\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \end{pmatrix}$$ to vanish. This amounts to $x_2/x_1=e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}/\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$; the given eigenvector satisfies this, and thus is a genuine solution. It's worth noting, though, that this isn't the *only* solution: any multiple of $(x_1,x_2)$ also solves this. The most obvious motivation for this choice of solution is that it's normalized: $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2=1$. Beyond that, it's just a fairly convenient option: $x_1$ will always be real, and the vector is explicitly $2\pi$-periodic in $\phi$.

Comment: This kind of calculations remind Pauli matrices.

Comment: @JeanMarie As it should: the matrix is of the form $X\sigma_x+Y\sigma_y+Z\sigma_z$ where $(X,Y,Z)$ are written in spherical coordinates. (The appearance of half-angles is best understood in the context of stereographic projection imo: Given the unnormalized solution $(x_1,x_2)=(1,e^{i\phi}\tan(\theta/2))$, the second coordinate is exactly the stereographic projection of $(X,Y,Z)$ onto the complex plane!)

Comment: @JeanMarie Agreed and (partially) adopted, though I prefer to retain sine/cosine over tangent to make the work more obvious to a newer practitioner.

Comment: Thank you @Semiclassical, didn't thought of getting such beautiful responses. Yes, this exaplanation is very helpful indeed, and now I can move to next chapters. Thank you so much. I will practice it my notebook.

Comment: Also, I think the expansion of this matrix will be like this --> \begin{pmatrix} x_2 e^{-i \phi} -x_1 \sin\frac{\theta}{2}/\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\\ x_1e^{i\phi} -x_2 \cos\frac{\theta}{2}/\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \end{pmatrix}

This is because $e^{i\phi}$ must be multiplied with $x_2$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also the "by inspection" technique is very helpful, since it allows us to reverse engineer or backtrack from the solution to a point, where the solution and the expanded question form meets.

Comment: @DebPrakashChatterjee you’re quite right, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Eignevalues of $A$ are roots of the characteristic equation
$$
\det(xI-A)=0
$$
in your case
$$
(x-\cos\theta)(x+\cos\theta)-(-e^{i\phi}\sin\theta)(-e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta)=x^2-1
$$
so the eigenvalues are $\pm1$.

Once you have an eigenvalue $\lambda$, you can find solutions to $Ax=\lambda x$ or $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ (as you say you're trying).  This is simple linear algebra with which you should be familiar (e.g. row reduction/Gaussian elimination).  Note that in this circumstance there is a whole subspace of solutions (i.e. eigenvectors are not unique).

In your case, there are two 1-dimensional eigenspaces (i.e. the eigenvector for each $\pm1$ eigenvalue is unique up to scalar multiplication).

In your example for $\lambda=1$, you can take something orthogonal to, say, the second row of $\lambda I-A$ (which will be orthogonal to the first row as well), say
$$
(1+\cos\theta, \ e^{i\phi}\sin\theta).
$$
Some trigonometric identities will get this to the answer you gave (as noted in another answer), say
$$
1+\cos\theta=2\cos^2(\theta/2), \quad \sin\theta=2\cos(\theta/2)\sin(\theta/2).
$$
These can be derived from the Pythagorean
$$
\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1
$$
and sum
$$
\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b, \quad \sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b
$$
identities.

Comment: Yes you are right. You have mentioned an approach to find the eigen value and eigen vectors. The problem with me is that, I do not remember all the formulas since I do not use them, and studying these things after maybe 4-5 year (since I am pass out of my college), hence taking some time to grasp the concepts and train my mind.

Once I am habituated with these, then I think I will be able to at least solve them. Thank you for your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to write an eigenvector of $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $v=\begin{pmatrix}b\\ \lambda-a\end{pmatrix}$. Using this result for your matrix, the eigenvector must be $v=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta\\ 1-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$.

> A good possibility is that the your eigenvector  is scalar multiple of $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ which is actually the case as:
> If $e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta=k\cos\theta/2$
> and $1-\cos\theta=ke^{i\phi}\sin\theta/2$
> then on dividing you get an identity $\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=\tan\theta/2$.